# Subdomain always redirects to main domain in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I've created a subdomain in Ubuntu Server which is in Azure Cloud, but it will always redirect to main domain

Here is my `apache.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xxx:80>
    ServerName admin.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/admin.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Also i've added the server IP in  `/etc/hosts` file

```
xx.xx.xx.xxx admin.example.com
```

Whats the problem?

Note: Created a `A host` record in in domain settings.

**Update**

Here is the output of `curl -v admin.example.com`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href                    ="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a hre                    f="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="                    findetrip/">findetrip/</a></td><td align="right">2016-06-16 04:52  </td><td alig                    n="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="                    test/">test/</a></td><td align="right">2016-06-16 05:40  </td><td align="right">                      - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at admin.example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host admin.example.com left intact
```

Comment: Could you post the results to  `curl -v admin.sample.com`

Comment: Updatee my question with the result

Comment: I must ask, but have restarted apache?

Comment: Yes i've restarted

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate DNS record for each of the main domain and the subdomain.  In other words, you need two A records - one for the main domain and another for the subdomain.